# Is there a more elegant way to convert a two-state string into a bitset than just by a 'for' loop?

Tags: c++, std-bitset

I wrote this code snippet to convert a two-state string (`"+++--+-"` or `"yynnny"`) into a `std::bitset`:

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::bitset<70> convertTwoStateString(std::string twoState)
{
    std::bitset<70> a{0b0};
    std::bitset<70> eins{0b1};

    for(const auto c : twoState) {
        if(c == '+') {
            a <<= 1;
            a |= eins;
        }
        if(c == '-') {
            a <<= 1;
        }
    }
    return a;
}


int main()
{
    std::string s{"-+--+++--+--+"};
    std::bitset<70> set = convertTwoStateString(s);

    std::cout << set << std::endl;
    //0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100111001001
}
```

Is there a more algorithmic and/or elegant way to do such a conversion?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "elegant".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) constructor can specify alternate characters representing `0/1`, so you can

```
std::string s{"-+--+++--+--+"};
std::bitset<70> set(s, 0, s.size(), '-', '+');
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9dfMdMPr5)

Answer (score 3):

Fun fact, bitset is not needed and the whole parsing can even be done at compile time if you want.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::size_t N>
static constexpr auto parse_bin(const char zero, const char one, const char(&string)[N]) 
{
    static_assert(N <= 8 * sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    static_assert(N > 1);

    std::uint32_t retval{};
    std::uint32_t mask = 1 << (N-2);
    std::size_t index{0ul};
   
    while(string[index] != 0)
    {
        auto c = string[index];
        if ((c != zero) && (c != one))
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument{"invalid input character"};
        }

        if (c == one) retval |= mask;
        mask >>= 1;
        ++index;
    }
    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(5 == parse_bin('0', '1', "101"));
    static_assert(9 == parse_bin('-', '+', "+--+"));
    static_assert(17 == parse_bin('n', 'y', "ynnny"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From C++23 onward, most (all?) of `std::bitset` functions (including constructors) are `constexpr` ;)

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer. But I need std::bitset's anyway since I want to apply in the next steps the binary logic operations.

Comment: @Suslik eh.. tbh there is nothing worse than `bitset` for bulk bitwise operations. Wait, maybe `vector<bool>` is worse. bitset was dsinged as a simple converter and accumulator of bit sequence, but otherwise? You always have either to convert to integral type or  build own  algorythms which iterate through a bitset.. while a CPU would use a single instruction.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie You're assuming a lot on OP's case: bulk operations, performance requirements, converts to unsigned at the end.

Comment: @YSC always nice to see more constexpr ;)

Comment: @OP you can always assign the calculated value to your bitset again.

Comment: @YSC I considered making the return type a template argument too but decided to keep it simple for this example (shouldn't be so hard to change this code for that though)