# binary logical operations with long bit sequences

Tags: c++, logical-operators, std-bitset

**C++ Problem:**

The minimum number of 1's should be found in the result of the XOR operation between a randomly generated N Bit sequence (N up to 50) `std::bitset<N> visit{0b01...110};` and a sequences of 1's, starting from `std::bitset<N> ones{0b0}`,`std::bitset<N> ones{0b1}`  and grows up to the MsB of `visit` so `ones{0b111...111}`;

```
std::vector<int> countPenalty(std::bitset<N> set)
{
    std::bitset<N> closing{0b0};
    std::bitset<N> eins{0b1};
    std::vector<int> countPen; 
    countPen.reserve(N);

    while(std::bit_width(closing.to_ulong()) <= std::bit_width(set.to_ulong()))
    {  
        std::bitset<N> tempSet = set ^ closing; 
        countPen.push_back(std::popcount(tempSet.to_ulong()));
        closing <<= 1;
        closing |= eins;    
    }
     return countPen;
}


int main()
{
   std::string s{"-11--111"};
   std::bitset<N> visitorSet(s, 0, s.size(), '0', '1');
   std::vector<int> penalties = countPenalty(visitorSet);
   auto minRes = std::min_element(penalties.begin(), penalties.end());
   std::cout << *minRes << std::endl; //2
   return 0;
}
```

Tasks similar to that one can be found very often in job interview preparations or c++ coding homeworks or leetcode (some similar task description I saw one is mentioned below). But I read on stackoverflow that to use big std. bitsets for binary logic operations is not a efficient solution. Actually why not? But is there a more elegant way which doesn't need to many code lines? I mean nobody wants to code a super complicated code on a job interview. And isn't bitset a good solution especially since c++20?

**"Real life context to the code":**

There is a ticket counter with a person working there. It just makes sense to have the ticket counter open when there are also clients who want to buy a ticket. So there are two cases of penalties:

- the ticket counter is open but there is no client
- the ticket counter is closed but there would be clients.

They make every day a list if there where clients (yes 1,no 0) in the *i*th hour. This will look like the following  `::string s{"01100111"};` for a day with 8 hours. Now there is the question if one should close the shop at specific hour to save money. The aim is to have as few penalties as possible.

Here a list of the visitors and the opening hours (0= ticket counter is open, 1= ticket counter is closed)

[image]

The XOR between the Visitor bitset and the opening/closing bitset gives me the set of penalties. There I can find the minimum of penalties which will show when it is best to close the ticket counter, to save money.

[image]

Comment: Forget about leetcode it is not in any form a good site to use. std::bitset is a convenience wrapper, not a high performant class. Investigate : [pop_count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount). Also see [is there are more elegant way to convert a two state string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005798/is-there-are-more-elegant-way-to-convert-a-two-state-string-into-a-bitset-then-j/77005958)

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer, thank you but sadly so many companies use it for their recruitment. And I have the impression that also hackerrank and codability have all a very similar way of creating questions. But do you have a better tip how to train C++ if the current work place doesn't use"advanced c++"?

Comment: Don't forget it is only for first round of recruiting (quick selection, on abstract thinking), in the later stages you still must show how to write correct/maintainable code. So in the end you should learn the language first, then also know about software engineering skills. If you start out with leetcode you will only learn the bad habits (non-readable,non-maintainable code optimized for one use case with all kinds of "tricks" that have no place in production code). Also cometitive coding gives you points for ANY solution, not a maintainable one

Comment: "advanced C++" is the old style C++ (almost like "C"), with raw pointers, naked new/delete where you cannot use the current standard library. Most people have that thinking backward too.

Comment: I usually give this advice : Learn C++ from : [a recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or from [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) that site is decent and pretty up to date.
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for reference material (and examples). When you have done all that keep using [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with the latest best practices since C++ keeps evolving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `std::bitset` is inefficient

> But I read on stackoverflow that to use big std. bitsets for binary logic operations is not a efficient solution.

This is true. `std::bitset` has requirements which make it inefficient, such as [`std::bitset::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/set) throwing exceptions when an index is out of range. This leads to significant codegen differences:

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <bit>
#include <cstdint>

auto set(std::bitset<64> x, std::size_t i) {
    x.set(i);
    return x;
}

auto set(std::uint64_t x, std::uint64_t i) {
    return x | (std::uint64_t{1} << i);
}
```

The first function compiles to:

```
set(std::bitset<64ul>, unsigned long):
        mov     rdx, rsi
        cmp     rsi, 64
        jae     .error_handling_stuff
        bts     rdi, rdx
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
.error_handling_stuff:
        [...]
```

The second function compiles to:

```
set(unsigned long, unsigned long):
        mov     rax, rdi
        bts     rax, rsi
        ret
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1d4Ph7hxG)*

*See more discussion here: [What is the performance of std::bitset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30295174/5740428)*

### `std::bitset` can be a good choice despite being inefficient

> But is there a more elegant way which doesn't need to many code lines? I mean nobody wants to code a super complicated code on a job interview. And isn't bitset a good solution especially since c++20?

I would still use `std::bitset` because outside of specific performance-critical use cases, `std::bitset` is *good enough*.
Worry about writing correct code first, then worry about making it efficient, if it's not efficient enough yet.

*See also [When is optimisation premature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/385506/5740428.)*

If you embrace `std::bitset`, you can improve code quality, which is going to impress your employer more than knowing about niche performance issues related to some standard library type:

```cpp
while(std::bit_width(closing.to_ulong()) <= std::bit_width(set.to_ulong()))
{  
    countPen.push_back((set ^ closing).count()); // use count() instead of std::popcount
    closing <<= 1;
    closing.set(0); // use set(0) instead of | here
}
return countPen;
```

If you're still worried about performance, you can create your own `std::bitset`-style container which doesn't perform run-time checks.